# Is it possible to declare auto variables with an if?

Tags: c++, auto

My Code is below.

```
struct conv{
    struct des
    {
        des(int a) {}
        des(int a, int b) {}
        des(int a, int b, int c) {}
    };
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;

if (a > 1)
{
    auto conv_desc = conv::des(1, 2, 3);
} else if(b > 1) {
    auto conv_desc = conv::des(1, 2);
} else {
    auto conv_desc = conv::des(1);
}
    return 0;
}
```

The code's pattern is extracted from mkldnn. The only thing I want to do is take auto conv_desc out of the if-else statement. 
I tried to declare auto conv_desc out of the if-else statement. 
It occurred an error:
Declaration of

> variable 'conv_desc' with deduced type 'auto' requires an initializer

Or if I used the pointer like below, I got a null pointer.
[image]

Another way got an error:
[image]

> Taking the address of a temporary object of type 'conv::des'

If I can't solve this problem, I will have to write a large piece of duplicate code in each branch.

Comment: Please _never_ paste errors as pictures.

Comment: please format your code properly.

Comment: In the second code, each constructed `conv::des` will be destructed at the end of each if-block.

Comment: `conv_desc` is a pointer why not just define it as `conv::des conv_desc` type and assign based on your if/else logic.

Comment: @PasserBy, So How do you express the errors. If you have an idea, please help me edit it.

Comment: @冯剑龙 "_So How do you express the errors._" In the same way, as you have provided your code (or, at least, one version of it). By copy-pasting it. One cannot copy-paste from screenshot.

Comment: By copy-pasting it *as text* to be precise. Also I must say that for some reason text on these images is even less readable than on usual images of text. It seems so blurry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `if` code into separate function:

```
conv::des make_des(int a, int b) {
  if (a > 1) {
    return conv::des(1, 2, 3);
  } else if(b > 1) {
    return conv::des(1, 2);
  } else {
    return conv::des(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  int c = 1;
  auto conv_desc = make_des(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use auto. If you need to declare a variable and can't assign a value yet, then auto can't be used.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // ...
    conv::des conv_desc; // calls default constructor.

    if (a > 1)
    {
        conv_desc = conv::des(1, 2, 3);
    } else if(b > 1) {
        conv_desc = conv::des(1, 2);
    } else {
        conv_desc = conv::des(1);
    }
    // conv_desc is initialized at this point.
    return 0;
}
```

You can't use a pointer like this

```
int *a;
{ // new scope
    int b = 5;
    a = &b; // error.
}
// b is no longer in scope here
```

When `b` goes out of scope, then `a` will be pointing at the address where `b` used to be, which is now no longer valid.

If you want to use a pointer then you can use new. However in that case you *must* release the memory afterwards.

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    conv::des *conv_desc = nullptr; // does not call default constructor.

    if (a > 1)
    {
        conv_desc = new conv::des(1, 2, 3);
    } else if(b > 1) {
        conv_desc = new conv::des(1, 2);
    } else {
        conv_desc = new conv::des(1);
    }
    if (conv_desc == nullptr) { /* memory allocation failed */ }
    // conv_desc is initialized at this point.
    // ...
    // remember to delete conv_desc
    if (conv_desc != nullptr) { delete conv_desc; conv_desc = nullptr; }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `null` does not exist in C++, use `nullptr` and you don't have to check if a variable is null before deleting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i got tossed an segfault last time I tried to delete a ptr with value \x00

Comment: You got UB somewhere else then.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot everyone in the post you linked uses `NULL` instead of `nullptr`

Comment: This is a good opportunity to suggest edits then. Most of these response are from 9 years ago. `nullptr` did not exist back then.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I guess I'm not up to date with the fancy new c++11 and 17 then. Never had much reason to anyway. I find it weird how a programming language like c++ is expanded and changed. Who determines what happens anyway? Someone has to write the specifications and the compilers have to keep up with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190845/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-falcoger).

Answer (score 2):

You also can use an immediately called lambda. This is a common pattern to make some variables const when they could not otherwise.

This solution is very similar to @yachoor answer but uses a lambda.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;

    // Kind of an inline function that is called immediately
    auto const conv_desc = [&]{
        if (a > 1) {
            return conv::des(1, 2, 3);
        } else if(b > 1) {
            return conv::des(1, 2);
        } else {
            return conv::des(1);
        }
    }();
    // Parens calls the function

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need any capture here, just pass `a` and `b` as ordinary parameters

Comment: @Caleth passing by capture is clearer for this idiom I think. There is a really high chance of comple optimisation, for both parameter passing and captures

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are making the code overly-complicated.  It is not clear why you would want to differentiate between these three constructors in this way.  Why not hide the complexity inside the object by using default values like this?

```
struct conv{
    struct des
    {
        des(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0) {
          if(a > 1) {
            /// do some logic
          } else if(b > 1) {
            // do some logic
          } else {
            // do some logic
          }

        }
    };
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  int c = 1;

  auto conv_desc = conv::des(a, b, c);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `if ... else` chain into a separate function, you can use `return`

```
struct conv
{
    struct des
    {
        des(int a) {
        }

        des(int a, int b) {
        }

        des(int a, int b, int c) {
        }
    };
};

conv::des make_conv_des(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > 1) {
        return conv::des(1, 2, 3);
    } else if(b > 1) {
        return conv::des(1, 2);
    } else {
        return conv::des(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    auto conv_des = make_conv_des(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: someone beat you to it

Comment: @FalcoGer Now people keeping `{` on the same line will brag that it is faster. DDD

Comment: how is that faster? it generates the same assembly... in fact white spaces have no bearing on anything in c/c++ (except to seperate words of course)

Comment: @FalcoGer I mean that it allows to write answers faster and beat people putting `{` on the separate line.